# Make a multi column button with a Gridview

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following XAML.  I want one button per row to encompass all the data.  Is this possible?

```
<ListView Name="ClosestListView">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="ShapeFileType" >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ShapeFileType}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>


                    <GridViewColumn Header="Address" >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=fullMatch}" MinWidth="100"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
... more columns and closing tags
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just looking to add a Click event to your Row, you would probably be better off adding a Click event to your `ListViewItem` or `GridViewCell`

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="HandleDoubleClick" />
</Style>
```

If you want to bind the click event to a `Command` in your ViewModel, I'd suggest using the `AttachedCommandBehavior` found [here](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/)

And if you really want a button that spams all columns, I would recommend looking into [Grid.SharedSizeGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748828.aspx#autolay_grids_issharedsizescope) to align your data

Answer (score 0):

I guess its more logical to just handle selectionchanged event.

```
  <ListView Name="ClosestListView" SelectionChanged="ClosestListView_SelectionChanged">
```